# Why isnt my HttpClient timing out?

Tags: c#, .net, http, dotnet-httpclient

I have some code like the following:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
  client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000);
  var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, myURI);
  var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
}
```

But when I go into the debugger, the code just hangs on await client.SendAsync(...). It throws no exception, and the control does not continue.  It hangs indefinitely.  Does anyone know what I am doirn wrong?

Comment: Are you blocking the async call with `.Result` or `.Wait`?

Comment: Maybe this bug? https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2857